# Yii2 Swiftmailer SMTP sometimes send, sometimes it fails

Tags: php, yii2, smtp, swiftmailer

I am sending an API request from one server to another and it should respond with an email. The problem is, sometimes it succeeds, sometimes it fails to send a message.

The log says:

```
[Swift_TransportException] exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.office365.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]' in /var/www/html/yii2/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269
```

My Configuration is:

```
'mail' => [
    'smtp' => 'smtp.office365.com',
    'user' => 'sample@mail.com',
    'password' => 'sample',
    'port' => 587,
    'encryption' => 'tls',
],
```

I tried redoing my backends but it seems the problem is the SMTP. Is this the case here? Or is it my backend? Whenever it fails, it responds with "Internal Server Error Occurred 500" but it doesn't log any errors in httpd.

I am using CentOS.

Comment: `getaddrinfo failed` is mostly lack of internet connectivity

Comment: So it's the server then? I think it's always connected to the internet and the site is always up. Do you think the iptables(firewall) could be the culprit?

Comment: Hmm sometimes pinging smtp.office365.com results in "ping: smtp.office365.com: Name or service not known"